# Divs not aligning side by side

Tags: html, css

I've been learning about divs over the past few months, and am now able to align divs side by side.

However, today I was working on my website, and my divs suddenly stopped lining up.

The divs in question are: `#dorsey_left`, `#dorsey_middle` and `#dorsey_right`.

When I remove `#dorsey_left` from the `HTML` document, `#dorsey_middle` and `#dorsey_right` align properly.  I'm guessing that the problem is related to `#dorsey_left`, but I can't find anything in the code.

This is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juaZg/).

Comment: When making jsFiddle examples, it's better to just make a small example of the issue you're having.  Don't just copy & paste your whole webpage there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find the solution by cleaning up your code. There are numerous syntax errors (unclosed quotes, children of `<ul>` that aren't `<li>`, etc). If your code passes [validation](http://validator.w3.org/) and the problem still exists try to simplify it so you get to the root of the problem by removing things that clearly aren't the problem.

Comment: That W3C Markup Validation Service was just the tool I needed.

Answer (score 0):

[layout](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp)

here is some simple examples please refer this

[alignment](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

check the size of each left | middle | right 
also check the main countainer

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will solve your problem which also has code in it for aligning 3 divs horizontally
http://codejigz.com/forget-tables-use-divscss-for-page-layouts/

Comment: yeah.. the blog is down. Sorry about that